# Imaginary header sent out by WP

Tags: wordpress

Since I migrated my page I get this annoying warning message. It shows up when I'm saving changes to saving anything (posts, settings...) and uploading images (that's where I noticed it). The message is as follows:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path/to/theme/functions.php:1)  in /path/to/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
```

Now I know this message should show up when there's something being output to the browser before a header is called. But my functions.php is clear, at least so it looks like in dreamweaver:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_action...
```

I don't see no output there...
What's wrong ? I didn't get the message before, on the test domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions.php file is probably encoded using [UTF8 BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom).

You should try to encode it without BOM, you can achieve this using, for example, notepad++.

Comment: I didn't really change anything and now it works. I wonder if it's only me, who gets this super strange WP behaviour. Anyway, thanks for the answer.